# 240 volt cheaper than 120 volt?

Tags: power

We just installed a 6' 240 volt baseboard heater (hardwired).  Will electrical consumption be less that using the plug in 120 volt electric heaters we used to use?

Comment: Not enough data supplied to answer your question. If you collect the necessary information you will be able to answer the question yourself. Find out the wattage rating of the hardwired heater. Then compare that to the sum of the wattage ratings of the previously used plug in heaters. Electrical consumption will be lower for the heater setup with the lower wattage numbers.

Comment: It will not be just the total number of Watts that's the issue... how long they are on will affect the Total used Watts.

Answer (score 1):

No. 1000W heater operating cost will be the same, either way. However, a 240Vac heaters generally use less copper (smaller conductors for lower current), so theoretically you save few cents on the purchase price.

Comment: -1 You have made an assumption that the heater wattage ratings are the same. There is no basis for that since no information was supplied by the OP with regard to the wattage of the heaters. You could qualify your answer indicating the assumption.

Comment: In this case @MichaelKaras I believe it is reasonable to assume that in a room or house ,when replacing a heater with another, it will require the same amount of power for heating no matter which resistive heating method is used.